# Right pad string with 0 in c

Tags: c

I am using zero left pad in c.Below is the implementation code.

```
unsigned char* LeftPadZero(unsigned char fa[], int flen)
{

    unsigned char *fout;
    int sz;
    sz = snprintf(NULL,0,"%s",fa);
    fout = (unsigned char*)malloc(flen+sz+1);
    if(flen > 0)
    {
        sprintf((char*)fout,"%0*d%s", flen , 0, fa);
    }
    else if(flen == 0)
    {
        fout = fa;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Length of number is negative\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return fout;

}
```

And now i am trying to do same for Right zero pad.But instead of padding with 0 .the length is getting printed.
EX: string000 this way it should print.In my case it is printing as string3

```
unsigned char* RightPadZero(unsigned char fa[], int flen)
{

    unsigned char *fout;
    int sz;
    sz = snprintf(NULL,0,"%s",fa);
    fout = (unsigned char*)malloc(flen+sz+1);
    if(flen > 0)
    {
        sprintf((char*)fout,"%s%0*d", fa , 0, flen);
    }
    else if(flen == 0)
    {
        fout = fa;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Length of number is negative\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return fout;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The length argument must be *before* the data argument, so try this

```
sprintf((char*)fout,"%s%0*d", fa , flen, 0);
```

instead of

```
sprintf((char*)fout,"%s%0*d", fa , 0, flen);
```

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function, paragraph 5:

> As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In
>   this case, an int argument supplies the field width or precision. The arguments
>   specifying field width, or precision, or both, shall appear (in that order) before the
>   argument (if any) to be converted.